# Struggling to appropriately mock asynchronous behaviour inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, node.js, postgresql, testing, jestjs

So I have a component in my application which contains the following logic upon mount:

```
const [dataFetched, setDataFetched] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await fetchIssues(); // Wait for issues to be retrieved from the DB
      setDataFetched(true);
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, []);

const fetchIssues = async () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/issues')
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch issues');
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      // Create Issue objects for each issue received
      const parsedIssues = data.map(issue => {
        return new Issue(*Issue Constructor Parameters*);
      });
      setPhaseTwoIssues(parsedIssues.slice(8));
      setIssues(parsedIssues.slice(0,8));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching issues:', error);
    });
};
```

I have a file made to mock the data:

```
const mockIssueData = [{Issue Object JSON copied directly from Postman}];

export default mockIssueData;
```

And I have a test file written to test that the data is successfully retrieved and the component is appropriately rendered:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import Scales from '../pages/scales/scales';
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import mockIssueData from '../__mocks__/mockIssueData';

beforeAll(() => {
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      ok: true,
      json: () => Promise.resolve(mockIssueData),
    })
  );
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fetch.mockClear();
});

afterAll(() => {
  fetch.mockRestore();
});


test('Scales Page Renders Necessary Components: TC01', async () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Scales />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  // Wait for the async operation to complete and UI to update
  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(/Balance/i)).toBeInTheDocument());

  // // Correct way to check if fetch was called
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:4000/issues');
});
```

However, I am getting the following error:
[Error i am encountering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZknIB.png)

FAIL  src/**tests**/scales-page.test.js
● Scales Page Renders Necessary Components: TC01

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

  138 |   // Function to fetch issues from the server
  139 | const fetchIssues = async () => {
> 140 |   fetch('http://localhost:4000/issues')
      |                                        ^
  141 |     .then(response => {
  142 |       if (response.ok) {
  143 |         return response.json();
```

I was expecting that having mocked the data it would be available to the component upon being imported into the test file.